# Dataframe object is not callable

Tags: geojson, geopandas, data-frame

I have a dataset contains latitude, longitude and temp. I tried to draw a contour map of temp based on latitude and longitude on the world map. I need to mark the contour line intervals also in the map.

I'm using conda myenv py as my interpreter and I installed `geojsoncontour` on my pycharm terminal.
I tried the below code got from a similar question with my own dataset.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import geojsoncontour
Import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

Data=pd.read_csv("df.txt")
Data1=Dataframe.to_csv('sample.csv', index=None)
Sample=pd read_csv('sample.csv',delim_whitspace=True)
temp = sample['temp']
lon = sample['lon']
lat = sample['lat']

y = np.linspace(min(lon), max(lon), 100)
x = np.linspace(min(lat), max(lat), 100)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = griddata((lat, lon), temp, (X, Y), method='cubic')
    
contour =    plt.contour(X,Y, Z)

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(sample(geojsoncontour.contour_to_geojson(
    contour=contour,
    min_angle_deg=3.0,
    ndigits=5,
    stroke_width=1))).set_crs("EPSG:4326")

m = gdf.explore(color=gdf["stroke"])

plt.show()
m
```

I'm getting an error `Typeerror : ' Dataframe object is not callable'`.

How can I solve the issue?

Sample of my data: (the whitespaces consist of tabs and spaces)

```
lat  lon    Temp    
5.00   40.00    298.22   
5.00   40.25    298.70
```

https://we.tl/t-uFLvPyYPIo?src=dnl

Comment: The error is on which row?

Comment: Post some actual code, that code will just produce a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Error is in the gdf assigning line.

Comment: Please don't include additional information as comments, edit your question so all the relevant info is in one place.  `sample` is a Dataframe, not a function, you can't call() it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @user2856 stated, `sample` is a DataFrame, not a function, you can't call it. That's, you cannot use it with parenthesis, like `sample(`.

Other problems arise because the whitespaces consist of tabs and spaces as in the image. To solve the problem you need to use `delim_whitespace=True` in `pd.read_csv`.

[image]

Use the following script. You need also `folium`, `mapclassify` packages installed.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import geojsoncontour
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import json

sample = pd.read_csv("df.txt", delim_whitespace=True)
temp = sample['temp']
lon = sample['lon']
lat = sample['lat']

y = np.linspace(min(lon), max(lon), 100)
x = np.linspace(min(lat), max(lat), 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = griddata((lat, lon), temp, (X, Y), method='cubic')
contour = plt.contour(X,Y, Z)

# geojsoncontour.contour_to_geojson returned a string
# So, needs to be converted to json
features = json.loads(geojsoncontour.contour_to_geojson(contour=contour,
                                                        min_angle_deg=3.0,
                                                        ndigits=5,
                                                        stroke_width=1))

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(features).set_crs("EPSG:4326")

m = gdf.explore(color=gdf["stroke"])
plt.show()
m
```

The result for a random sample:

[image]

Comment: I'm getting an error : temp=sample['Temp'], indexer=self.columns.get_loc(key),raise keyError (key) from err keyError:'Temp'. How can I resolve this.

Comment: Check column name. Key name is case-sensitive. `'Temp'` not equals `'temp'`.

Comment: Column name is Temp, I used that Temp. Then also I'm getting the same . My data example is like lat as 5.00 and lon as 40.00 Temp as 298.55

Comment: I added a sample ...I can't add a link to it.. because I'm a beginner of this community...All my data of lon lat and temp is float

Comment: Now the keyError is just changed Temp to lat. Is it the Problem of my data...then how can I solve the issue!!!

Comment: Yes , I done that in the above question section